# Глотком поглощать - тавтология или сойдёт?

Tags: тавтология

> Она благосклонно кивает, принимая любимый напиток из рук своего
>   кавалера. Аккуратно снимает крошечной ложечкой волшебную пенку и
>   кормит ею обожателя. Затем **глотком поглощает** обжигающую
>   восхитительную жидкость, возвращает чашечку и медленно закрывает окно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тавтологию лучше убрать:

(1) *Затем **одним глотком выпивает**  обжигающую восхитительную жидкость, возвращает чашечку и медленно закрывает окно.*

(2) *Затем **разом поглощает** обжигающую восхитительную жидкость, возвращает чашечку и медленно закрывает окно.*

Comment: Спасибо за "разом"! ))) Но я отправила текст вчера, сопроводив: *НАШЛА ЧУДНЫЙ СИНОНИМ: ХЛЕБОК! ХЛЕБКОМ ПОГЛОЩАЕТ!* Хлебок, имхо, "вкуснее" разома... )))

Answer (score 1):

**Одним** глотком можно и поглощать (связь двух слов - только этимологическая), а вот просто "глотком" (что-то с жидкостью делать) вынуждает задуматься: а как иначе поглощают или пьют что-то? А может, она не всю жидкость из чашки поглотила? Не вполне изящная авторская недосказанность.